Absurd inequality arising while proving the homogeneous property of integrals
To prove $\int_a^b cf(x) dx=c\int_a^b f(x)dx$ for $c>0$. Refer page 85 of apostol calculus for more details.
Let an integrable function $f(x)$ be approximated by all step-functions $t_1(x)$ and $s_1(x)$ from above and below such that $s_1(x)\leq f(x)\leq t_1(x)$, defined over $[a,b]$.
Then $cs_1(x), ct_1(x)$ will bound $cf(x)$ likewise.
Say the integral of any such $s_1(x)$ be $s_1$, of $cs_1(x)$
be $s$, and $S_1$, $S$ be their respective sets.
$s_1\le \sup S_1 \\ cs_1\le c\sup S_1\\s\le \sup S\le c\sup S_1\tag{1}\label{eq1}$.
There exists $s_1$ for all $x>0$ such that $s_1>\sup S_1 -x$. For $x=\frac 1n$, where $n\in Z^+$
$s_1>\sup S_1 - \frac1n\\s>c\sup S_1-\frac cn\\s+\frac cn>c\sup S_1 \tag{2}\label{eq2}$
From these two sets of equations we can obtain $\sup S +\frac 1n>c\sup S_1\ge \sup S$, which will prove that the lower of integral of $cf(x)$ is $cf$, where f is the integral of $f(x)$.
But my question is that from the inequalities we can also obtain $s +\frac 1n>c\sup S_1\ge s$. Since this is true for all $n$, all $s$ must be equal to $c\sup S_1$ which is absurd.

The set $S$ is a singleton ($S={s}$) so $s=\sup S$. More importantly, $\sup S\le c\sup S_1$ is wrong.

@AnneBauval How is it wrong? Firstly S is not a sigleton (why do you think it is), secondly the inequalities are correct, $cs_1$ is $s$, and for every s $c\sup S_1$ is greater, so it is upper bound for $s$, now of course the least upper bound of all $s$ can't be greater than it. so $\sup S\le c\sup S_1$

Firstly, $S$ is a singleton: there is only one $s$ in $S$, namely the one you defined (the integral of $cf(x)$, where $c$ and $f(x)$ are fixed from the beginning). Secondly, $cs_1$ is not $s$. You only have (assuming $c\ge0$, as you tacitely did): $$cs_1\le s$$ for every step function $s_1(x)\le f(x)$, so $cS_1\le s$.

@AnneBauval It was a typo. $s$ is the integral of $cs_1$

The point is that $s\le c\sup S_1$ for every $s$, whereas you only have $s+\frac1n>c\sup S_1$ for some $s$, which depends on $n$.

for side-mark it is $s_1$ instead of $s$, typo from my part.  For the  second part of your answer, the inequality must be correct for all $n$(The inequality in side-remark is a property of  supremum where $x$ can be any positive number)

Since you corrected your last typo, I remove my side remark. As for your main question: beware the order of quantifiers: for each $n$ there exists an $s$ (not the converse!).

How does this explain the result from that inequality: Since the inequality is true for all $n$, $s$ must be equal to $c\sup S_1$ as if it is lesser than that archimedean property on n, s,  $c\sup S_1 - s>0$ will lead to contradiction

Again: you "since the inequality true for all $n$, $s$ must be..." is flawed because there is no fixed $s$ in this inequality. Again: $s$ depends on $n$. Maybe things get clearer to you if you write $$\forall n,;\exists s_{\color{red}n},;s_{\color{red}n}+\frac1n>c\sup S_1.$$
